# Get a specific property from an object in an array if true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a object that looks like this:

```
export default class Widget {
public title: string;
public url: string;
public icon: string;
public id: string;
public defaultWidget: boolean;
  }
```

I have an array with all the widgets, allWidgets. I want to extract the id from this array WHEN the defaultWidget is true.

So I want to extract a property from this object (id) WHEN another property (defaultWidget) is true. So far I have:

```
const newArray = allWidgets.map(element => element.defaultWidget);
```

However, it only returns true for every true object it have. But I want it to return the ID where the defaultWidget is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get widgets with `defaultWidget === true` and then use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get ids.

Both `filter` and `map` will create new arrays.

Or you could try use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to compose all of it.

In case of `reduce` you will create new array once.

```
const newArray = allWidgets.filter(widget => widget.defaultWidget).map(widget => widget.id)

// or

const newArray = allWidgets.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  if (elem.defaultWidget) {
    acc.push(elem.id);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

const newArray = allWidgets.filter(obj => obj.defaultWidget).map(obj => obj.id);

The above array will give you the list of id's where **defaultWidget** is true.

Here Filter will filters the array based on the condition and map creates a new array containing only id's

Answer (score 1):

in JavaScript you can try this code: `returns list of ids if married = true`

```
// Try edit msg
var emps = [
 {id: 1, name: "Employee1", married: true},
 {id: 2, name: "Employee1", married: false},
 {id: 3, name: "Employee1", married: true}
]

// getting list of ids of employees if married is true
var idList = emps.map(obj => {
  if (obj['married'] == true) {
    return obj.id 
  } 

})

// removing null values from list 
idList = idList.filter(ele => ele!=null);

console.log(idList);   

// output: [1, 3]
```